# How do we validate header parameter value on quarkus controller for unit test

Tags: rest, unit-testing, controller, reactive-programming, quarkus

In a quarkus application, I am trying to write unit test for Controller for the resource method where I need to validate certain header parameters. so How do we validate?

```
@Path("/abcs")
public class ABCController {
...

  @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @ResponseStatus(CREATED)
    public Uni<AbcResponse> createABC(
            @Context HttpHeaders httpHeaders,
            @Valid @ConvertGroup(to = ValidationGroups.Post.class)
            AbcRequest abcRequest) {
String apiKey = httpHeaders.getRequestHeader("X-API-Key").get(0);

        if (StringUtils.isBlank(apiKey)) {
            throw new RestFulPayoutException("X-API-Key is missing on headers", Response.Status.FORBIDDEN);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a `@QuarkusTest` and with `RestAssured` perform a call to your endpoint with various header values and check for response.
All information are available at [Quarkus documentation](https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-testing#testing-a-specific-endpoint).

Comment: Thank you Luca for the answer

Comment: YW. If my answer solve the problem, please accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

After going through provided Quarkus documentation and on the internet. I have added header parameter on the unit test as follows

```
Response abcdResponse = given()
                .body(abcRequest_json_string)
                .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
                .headers(Map.of("X-API-Key","test-api-key"))
                .when()
                .post();
```